# DATE validation using regex in awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

How to validate date column in a file using regular expression in awk ?? My code doesn't seem to be working with awk.

**my code**

```
awk -F '|' BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
{ if 
($1 ~ /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2} [AP]M\z/)
print
}' file > file.out
```

**file contents -**

```
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
06-JUN-2022|09876
2022-JAN-2011 22:12:33|23120
```

**expected output**

```
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

Comment: what is your `awk` version (`awk --version`)? please update the question with the exact code you're using (the current code has a few typo/syntax issues and doesn't work under `GNU awk`)

Comment: GNU awk 4.2 .1 is the version that I am using

Comment: Awk uses POSIX extended regular expressions, which don't include constructs like `\d`. Use `[[:digit:]]` instead. No `\z` either.

Comment: Validating dates in regex is a fool's errand. If you're actually looking to extract date-like strings then that is certainly do-able.

Comment: (GNU awk recognizes `\'` as end-of-string like perl's `\z`)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  - I want to run a check on the datetime column of my file.

Comment: @NadiaAlice : out of curiosity , may i ask why refrain from upgrading to gawk 5.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `GNU awk` the `\d` and `\z` sequences are not valid regex operators (a quick web search doesn't show these as valid regex operators in a couple others flavors of `awk` though by no means an exhaustive search).

I'd suggest replacing the `\d` with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`; as for the `\z` you could try `\>` or `\y`.

One other issue is the use of `.` as a wildcard match in the time component; if you know all times will use a colon (`:`) as a delimiter then I'd use an explicit colon.

Rolling these changes into the current code (and fixing a couple cut-n-paste/syntax issues):

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}
{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} [AP]M\y/)
print
}'
```

This generates:

```
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

**NOTES:**

- obviously (?) this code assumes a specific date/time format and thus ...
- this code will not match on other valid date/time formats (eg, won't match on `2021/12/31`)
- the use of `[0-9]` opens you up to matching on strings that are not valid dates and/or times, eg, this code will match on `99/99/2022` and `99:99:99`); OP can address some of these by limiting the series of digits that can be matched in a given position (eg, `[0-2][0-9]` for hours) but even this is problematic since `29` will match but is not a valid hour
- as alluded to in comments ... validating dates/times is doable but will require a good bit more code (alternatively run a web search on `bash awk validate dates times` for additional ideas)

Comment: using `$` instead of `\y` should work, because the line is split at `|`

Comment: the command could be reduced to `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$1 ~ /^([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{1,2}:){2}[0-9]{1,2} [AP]M$/'`

Comment: @markp-fuso : strangely enough, 24:00 (midnight) and sometimes even 25:00 (1am - seen it once in Osaka) is considered a valid time in Japan

Comment: @Fravadona : the command could be much further reduced by skipping the OFS part and directly setting the entire regex, plus trailing "[ | ]", as FS itself. Main body then would only check for  NF == 2. ps : setting { 1 , 2 } instead of just { 2 } for seconds and minutes is superfluous here  because the first half of the regex mandated Y-M-D, and it would be super rare to ever see YMD plus single digit for HH or SS.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' '{printf "%s",(match($1, /^[0-1][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-9]{4}.*[AP]M$/)) ? $0"\n" : "" }' file 
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `\d` and `\z` aren't recognized by any of the mandatory POSIX tools, including awk, sed, and grep (except, GNU grep with `-P`).

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '/^([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} [AP]M\|/' file
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} [AP]M$/' file
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

The above just checks that the input **looks** like a timestamp though, so it'd accept nonsense date and time values like `57/95/0000 35:72:65 PM`. To actually check that the input is a **valid** timestamp would be this in GNU awk for time functions and the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="|" }
match($1,/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}) ([AP]M)$/,t) {
    if ( (t[7] == "PM") && (t[4] < 12) ) {
        t[4] += 12
    }
    inDt  = sprintf("%04d %02d %02d %02d %02d %02d",t[3],t[1],t[2],t[4],t[5],t[6])
    secs  = mktime(inDt)
    outDt = strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S",secs)
    if ( inDt == outDt ) {
        print
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
```

Note the difference in this output of that script vs the first scripts given this modified input file:

```
$ cat file
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
06-JUN-2022|09876
2022-JAN-2011 22:12:33|23120
57/95/0000 35:72:65 PM|nonsense date and time numbers
02/29/2020 05:10:20 AM|this is a leap year
02/29/2021 05:10:20 AM|this is a not leap year
```

```
$ awk -F'|' '$1 ~ /^([0-9]{2}\/){2}[0-9]{4} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} [AP]M$/' file04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
57/95/0000 35:72:65 PM|nonsense date and time numbers
02/29/2020 05:10:20 AM|this is a leap year
02/29/2021 05:10:20 AM|this is a not leap year
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
04/21/2014 02:04:55 AM|34536
12/31/2021 03:29:15 AM|87612
02/29/2020 05:10:20 AM|this is a leap year
```

Change each `{2}` to `{1,2}` if you can have other input with single digits instead of always double as shown in the example you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Because `\z`asserts position at the end of the string, but in your case you have pipe symbol and I assume process ID, which means there's no match between your input string and regex.

If you are certain that this is all that the line contains, you can try and match everything after A/P M:
`^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2} [AP]M.*`

Otherwise, match till next distinct delimiter.

Comment: Wrong RE dialect.